# How to stop udp socket thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

This are some the code that I used for my udp server. My problem is when I call the method terminate, It will only stop the listening loop after it receives another message from udp socket. I want to stop the thread immediately when I call terminate method. Or is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

```
    class StartThread:
        def __init__(self):
            self._running = True
            self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
            self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1234))        

        def terminate(self):
            self._running = False

        def run(self):    
            while  self._running:
                data, addr = self.s.recvfrom(1024)

c = StartThread()
t = Thread(target=c.run)
t.start()
```

Comment: You can have a look at `import select` or `import twisted`(needs to be installed) for alternatives to threads.

Answer (score 2):

in your terminate method, you can call `s.shutdown()` and `s.close()`. this should trigger the  blocking call to terminate immediately.

Comment: With which method have to run shutdown? SHUT_RD? SHUT_RDRW?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to staticd answer, (which is fine), there are alternatives:

You could use a volatile boolean 'terminate' member that is checked after every recvfrom() return.  Set the flag, then send an empty datagram on localhost to make the call return.

You could check every received datagram for a value that has no other meaning in your protocol, eg 'STOP'.  Send such a datagram on localhost.

TBH, I would just shutdown() the socket, it's easier.